# PowerShell's Get-ExecutionPolicy returns different values

Tags: c#, powershell

Depending on the method I used to get the execution policy setting for PowerShell, I get two different values.

If I run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in a PowerShell prompt, I get 'Unrestricted'.

If I use the following code, I get 'Restricted'.

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
    runspace.Open();

    var pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-ExecutionPolicy");

    foreach (var result in pipeline.Invoke())
    {
        var restriction = ((ExecutionPolicy)result.BaseObject);
        break;
    }
}
```

Again, I get 'Restricted' with the following code:

```
using (var invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
    foreach (var result in invoker.Invoke("Get-ExecutionPolicy"))
    {
        var restriction = ((ExecutionPolicy)result.BaseObject);
        break;
    }
}
```

I also checked in the registry here: `HKEY_Local_Machine\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.Powershell\ExecutionPolicy`
and there it says *Unrestricted*.

Why do I get a different result? Is my code incorrect perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you implementing a custom host?  If so, the default execution policy would be restricted and would need to be set for that host (under ShellIds).

Either way, you should be able to execute this command first in your code to override the setting:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope process
```

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately, this code will be running in a Windows service. For the moment, I am testing it in a windows application. What rights will I need to be able to override the setting?

Comment: Also, is there a way to know what is the overall setting? That way, I will be able to run my PS script under that policy, and if the rights are not enough (for example if the policy is set to restricted), then it will fail (which I am ok with).

Comment: No special rights are required to override the setting AFAIK. Keeping in mind that the setting is per shellid/host, Get-ExecutionPolicy tells you the effective policy for that host.  The effective policy is determined by evaluating settings a various priority levels from machine group policy down to local machine policy.  See the help topic `about_execution_policies` for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith. For anyone else looking for that help topic, I will save a google search: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347641.aspx