# Powershell : Execution Policy

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have been running my code for past few months by doing this -

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

But, something weird is happening and I am getting this **error** always -

> Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the
>   setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope. 
>   Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
>   execution policy of "Unrestricted". Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List"
>   to view your execution policy settings. For more information, please
>   see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy."

I have referred these links but no luck -

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2011/12/07/set-executionpolicy-windows-powershell-updated-your-execution-policy-successfully-but-the-setting-is-overridden-by-a-policy-defined-at-a-more-specific-scope.aspx
- http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2010/09/issues-with-configuring-powershell.html
- http://www.howtogeek.com/106273/how-to-allow-the-execution-of-powershell-scripts-on-windows-7/

  **I am loading the Powershell using C# on a 64-bit Windows 7 via a 32-Bit Winforms Application using .Net 4.0**

  What is the exact setting which I need to do such that I do not get this error on any system ? [Everything was working fine]. What should these values be on any system such that I am able to call Powershell from C# seamlessly -

**Get-ExecutionPolicy -List**

> ```
> MachinePolicy                                                           
> UserPolicy                                                           
> Process                                                        
> CurrentUser                                                        
> LocalMachine
> ```

Comment: The output of `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` should be showing you the execution policy per scope.

Comment: It is showing Unrestricted for LocalMachine. But, in between I get the error as I have mentioned above. I don't know why. Its really frustrating !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see output like this from `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`:

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined 
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

Once you see the scope that has the undesired setting, you can reset it like so:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Scope <scope-name>
```

That is assuming you have permission to do so.

Comment: But I get the error while executing from C# code & at that time I do not have any control to reset the scope ?

Comment: Can the sysadmin do something at group policy level forever such that I do not have to touch script based code at all for this thing at least (Win7-32 & 64 bit, Win2k8 R2)

Comment: Whoa - are you running this from your own host i.e. are you hosting the PowerShell engine in your own C# app?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Have a look at the answer to this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339093/powershell-get-executionpolicy-returns-different-values

Comment: Thanks Keith. I am not doing any custom hosting. I am just calling into the Powershell runtime from C# using `Powershell.Create` on these lines - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706580(v=vs.85).aspx.